# Memory leak, connection pool full; Question: with dao's in cdi (weld): when are connections closed?

Tags: jpa, weblogic, cdi, dao, weld

My question is: if you work with dao's in cdi (weld), in weblogic e.g., when are connections opened and closed? We use session beans, container managed transactions.

We see:

```
weblogic.jdbc.extensions.PoolLimitSQLException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceLimitException: No resour   4205 ces currently available in pool VVVDB to allocate to applications, please increase the size of the poo   4205 l and retry..
```

Maybe it is because of the following dao:

```
@RequestScoped
public class RRRDaoImpl implements RRRDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "VVVDB")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Boolean hasVVVIdRRR(String rrrKind, String externNummer, Long vvvId) {
        RRR reg = em.find(RRR.class, new RRRId(rrrKind, externNummer, vvvId));
        return reg != null;
    }
```

The persistence.xml looks like:

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="VVVDB" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/VVVDB</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: The setting `<jta-data-source>jdbc/VVVDB</jta-data-source>` directs the JPA implementation to use a `DataSource`. This is an *application server managed* connection pool. The application server creates and destroys it when it thinks it is the appropriate time. Connections are opened and closed according to the connection pool configuration.

Comment: As for the PoolLimitSQLException: it may be that you have too many concurrent requests, all accessing the DB at the same time. This is the good scenario (lots of customers :) you will probably have to increase the resources. Otherwise you have a resource leak. I don't see something suspicious in the RRRDaoImpl. Are you using the datasource manually, meaning outside JPA?

Comment: @Nikos, thanks! Indeed, I found that the datasource is also used manually and in a place there was forgotten to close the connection.